# Sci-Fi TV show from mid-to-late 80's, Family, Other Planet, "Good Food" in grocery

Tags: story-identification, aliens

Does anyone remember a TV show from the mid-to-late '80's that was somewhat sci-fi (ish) where a family gets either transported to another planet, or to another time/dimension where everything is a utopian society.   There's not much I recall except that I thought the young teen son in the show was handsome (shut up, I was 11) and when the mom & daughter went to the grocery store, all the food items are labeled generically (white with black letters) and all the labels say "good food".  Anyone recall the name of this show?

Comment: Maybe it's on this list? https://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=1980s%20sci%20fi%20tv%20shows

Comment: I remember this, but I thought it was an episode of Outer Limits. Well that explains why I could never find that episode hahaha.

Comment: see OP comment below confirming duplicate status

Comment: In a “you gotta be kiddin’ me” way, I found that near me is apparently a craft service food supply place. It’s name? Good Food. It’s housed in anonymous bland buildings. I find that absolutely hilarious.

Answer (score 5):

This appears to be the very short-lived CBS TV series **Otherworld**.

[image]

From the [Wikipedia description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otherworld_(TV_series)):

> In the first episode, the Sterling family (Hal, June, Trace, Gina, Smith) take a tour of the interior of the Great Pyramid of Giza at the same time as a once-in-ten-thousand-years conjunction of the planets. Inside - Hal not willing to give in to the guide's money scam - they are abandoned by their guide, and as they try to get out, they are mysteriously transported to another planet which may or may not be in a parallel universe.

There's a daughter and two sons, which fits what you describe in your query (although I can't vouch for the handsomeness of the teen son).

Also, by searching "Good food" in conjunction with the title, I found [this site](http://www.tvobscurities.com/articles/otherworld/), which has a comment at the very bottom:

> I remember my brother and I watching what was I think the pilot episode. The family is still trying to figure out what happened and the wife goes to the market and finds all the cans marked “Good Food”. When she asks a clerk what it is in the cans he simply says matter-of-factly “It’s ‘Good Food'”, as if that completly answered her question.
>   After that for the longest time whenever someone asked what a given dish was my brother would pipe up matter-of-factly, “It’s ‘Good Food'”.

Comment: Yes!!!!  This is exactly it!!!  Thank you! :)